# Redux DevTools showing incorrect history

Tags: redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I've encountered an issue with Redux DevTools where it displays history unrelated to my application. I initially suspected that this might be due to the inspect window being open, but my investigations proved otherwise. Even when no user actions (clicks, keyboard inputs, mouse movements, etc.) are performed, the state is displayed during the loading process. However, towards the end, this state information transitions to displaying Chrome's actions instead.

Is there a way to configure the Redux DevTools extension in such a manner that it only shows actions related to the exact URL of my application?

Thank you in advance for any help!

[image: History]

Comment: Is there more than just your React app with a Redux store running in the browser context? Have you selected your app's instance to monitor in the extension? AFAIK there's nothing to configure other than just selecting the store instance you want to observe.

Comment: No, there is only one app running!
Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who faced the same issue, I found the solution:
[image]

From the above, you can choose the NgRx Store DevTools, which filters and shows only your actions.